# How to fix error *No module named 'lgsvl', after running python script for running LG simulator?

Tags: python

I am trying to run python script by following the procedure stated in running the LGSVL simulator for the autonomous driving scenario but it is giving me an error saying no module found lgsvl.

I am running the code as well as the lg simulator in the python folder. python version 3.6 is used.

Comment: This error usually means either the module `lgsvl` has not been installed to the `site-packages`, or the path to your `site-packages` is not known to the environment where you attempt to run the simulator. Can you post a link to the steps you are using?

Comment: steps followed. 1.downloaded lg simulator and running exe file for running simulator.    2. running simulator in a way shown in simulator support to be able to run python API. 3. installed python 3.6 in windows directory. 4. installed python API in the same windows directory. 5. running python API

Comment: i only have 1 python version and i am trying to install the dependencies through "pip3 install --user -e" in PythonAPI folder but still it is not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, the description of the steps doesn't help us recreate the issue. Can you post a web link to those steps (if they are available on the web?) The switch `--user` tells `pip` to install the package exclusively in the user's path, and not the system path, This may be the problem (the path may not be pointing to the user only site-packages.) See here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id25. 

Perhaps try installing without the `--user`

Comment: https://www.lgsvlsimulator.com/docs/python-api/

Comment: i am using this link to use the Python Api

Comment: whenever i use pip3 command whether is user directory or in Python API directory it gives the following reply: C:\windows\System32>pip3 install --user -e

Usage:
  pip3 install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip3 install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip3 install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip3 install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip3 install [options] <archive url/path> ...

-e option requires 1 argument

Comment: the problem is solved. i had to install in PythonAPI and the dot at the end of the command is very important for the command to run. so it is pip3 install --user -e.